# Change Plus to Minus Sign When Collapsed By Altering :before

Tags: jquery, html, css

As the title suggests, I want to change the plus sign to a minus sign when it is collapsed by altering the plus:before (by displaying none or something so it looks like a minus sign.) Currntly my code works and collapses as intended. Demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRjZwL).

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #1<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul>
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #2<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #3<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #4<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #5<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.box p').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).parent().children('.box ul');
    if (!target.is(":visible")) {
      $('.box ul').slideUp();
      $(target).slideDown();
    } else {
      $(target).slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have a `minus` class which works just like the `plus` class but displays a minus sign.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.box p').click(function(){
      var target = $(this).parent().children('.box ul');
      if (!target.is(":visible")) {
        $('.box ul').slideUp();
        $(target).slideDown();
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
      }
      else {
        $(target).slideUp();
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('minus').addClass('plus);
      }
    });
});
```

BTW, why are you not simply setting the css `content` property of the span to '+' (or '-') ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add class `minus` and toggle this one with plus every expand-collapse event on item.

#### [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgVxGM)

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.box p').click(function(){
      var target = $(this).parent().children('.box ul');
      if (!target.is(":visible")) {
        $('.box ul').slideUp();
        $(target).slideDown();
        $(this).children(".box .plus").toggleClass("plus, minus");
      }
      else {
        $(target).slideUp();
        $(this).children(".box .plus").toggleClass("plus, minus");
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #EEE;
  width: 400px;
}
.box p {
    color: #;
    display: block;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box ul {
    display: none;
}
.box li {
    color: #666;
    padding-left: 12px;

}
.box .plus, .box .minus {
     color: #3BB1D0;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 14px;
    bottom: -6px;
}
.box .plus:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: 7px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 21px;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 2px
}
.box .plus:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: -8px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 4px;
    top: 8px;
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute
}
.box .minus:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: 7px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 2px
}
.box .minus:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: -8px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 4px;
    top: 8px;
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #1<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul>
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #2<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #3<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #4<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="box-item">
    <p>Item #5<span class="plus"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
      <li>List Item #1</li>
      <li>List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```